# How to export SmartList Definition?

Tags: sql, sql-server, view, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-gp

I just want to export SQL Query of the SmartLists for backing up and transfer to other system. Is any way to do so?

Comment: What version of GP? If I am not mistaken, some of the newer releases have an Import/Export feature for SL. In older versions, IIRC they are in the DYNAMICS database under ASI tables. They may not be easy to migrate through SQL though.

Comment: I have GP 2016 Version. I see that Export/Import to XML. It looks like exporting data but I want "SELECT * FROM ..." statement. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In GP2018, you can select a given SmartList and then select "Options - Display SQL...". From there, you can just copy/paste the SQL to wherever you need it to be.

I'm also trying to reverse engineer SQL from the Dynamics tables, but I haven't got far on that endeavor yet.